# Two UICollectionViews manager by one controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uicollectionview

I have a UIViewController that is embedded in a navigation controller. The navigation controller has a switcher with 2 items on it.

First item shows a UICollectionView with images, and the second UICollectionview needs to show an Image with some description text.

I have assigned the delegates in the ViewController for these *two* UICollectionViews to self.When the Viewloads, the first UICollectionView shows all the images. When I click on the second switcher item, none of the delegate methods like numberOfItemsInSection, cellForItemAtIndexPath gets triggered.

In viewDidLoad I hide the second UICollectionView and when the user hits the second switcher, I hide the first UICollectionView and unhide the second UICollectionView.

I cant figure out what is the issue. I tried using a [self.secondCV setNeedsDisplay] to trigger a redraw, but that dosent seem to work as well.

Anyone who has tried doing something similar or can explain what I might be doing wrong here ?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: You debugged to check that the delegate relationship was set at runtime? And you called `reloadData` on the second collection view?

Comment: Yes it was a copy paste error. I was setting the delegate but not the datasource. So it works now ...